# How to compare a List<long> with a comma-separated ids, using linq to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have Interest `Ids` column in user profile. & a `List<long> interest ids`. I want to fetch user profiles matching interest ids in List using Entity Framework.

Ex.

- Sam   1,5,9,13,4,8
- John  2,7,13,9
- Kettie 1,4,8,12,15

List: {4,8}

I want output as {Sam,Kettie}

**Update:** Db Structure-

```
public class UserProfile
{    
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Interests { get; set; }  //Store comma separated Interest Ids here 
}

public class Interest
{
    public long InterestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I achieve this by

```
var interestIds = db.Interests.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(query))
        .Select(i=> i.InterestId)
        .ToList();
var profiles = new List<UserProfile>();
foreach (var id in interestIds)
{
    profiles.AddRange(db.UserProfiles
        .Where(p=> p.Interests.Contains(id.ToString()))
        .ToList());
}
return profiles;
```

But, when dealing with huge records it takes long time to execute so I want help to optimise this.

Comment: Dear, please do not get me wrong, But your request sounds like: "I have a task, please do it for me". Please read the rools of the stack overflow and try to follow. You can definetly manage it!

Comment: Provide some demo code of yours...

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I have updated my question. I hope that satisfies the rules & you have a solution for me :)

Comment: @SarangK As you have `Id` both in `Interests` and `UserProfiles`, you should make it the foreign key between them so you can use navigation properties

Comment: You did not provide sql table structure .. does `Sam 1,5,9,13,4,8` is stored in a single column .. or you have two separate column to store `Sam` and `1,5,9,12,...`

Comment: now it is better! this one might help you an idea https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Seeing as multiple userprofiles can share interests and interests will belong to multiple userprofiles, there should be a linking table in between (m<->n) where a key consists of profileid AND interestid, together with possible extra info. This way simple joining is performed to do queries, so that you can easily get the interestids into the query, then by the join (or in-lang navigational properties), you also get the data for the user profile.

Comment: @RichardEriksson Thanks for the help. I know I can achieve by this way but that require more modification in live application. So I was thinking if there is any tricky solution in Linq or EF for this.

Comment: Ok .. Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if the answer is not exactly what you are looking for as I'm unfamiliar with entity-framework, but looking at it purely from a C# point of view:

For every id in your interestIds you are filtering your entire database every time (and doing this by checking a collection on each entry) - I would imagine you are incurring a performance penalty here.

If possible, you could map each interest id to a list of user names. This only needs to be done once and may perform better - something like:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<long, List<string>>();
foreach(var user in userProfiles)
{
    foreach(var interest in user.Interests)
    {
        List<string> names;
        if(dict.TryGetValue(interest, out names))
            names.Add(user.Name);
        else
            dict.Add(interest, new[] { user.Name }.ToList());
    }
}

long[] interestIds = new[] { 4, 8 };

HashSet<string> profiles = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var interestId in interestIds)
    profiles.UnionWith(dict[interestId]);
```

So iterating over every interest for every user, you then add each interest as a key and add the user to the list of users for that key.

You can then iterate over your list of interestIds and pull the matching list out user names out of the dictionary (note the HashSet - this will stop you getting duplicate names for users who match more than one interest).

Comment: Thanks for ans. Correct me if I am wrong, but for above code I need to fetch all the User profiles from database also there is a nested foreach so don't you think it will increase response time & looks a bit complex too.

Comment: In your example, does it not fetch all user profiles and then reduce them using .Where on every interestId? This may be where my lack of understanding of entity-framework comes in to play though!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to execute your query in `sql server only once` ..  I checked it using `profiler` and it's better because when `foreach loop iterate`  .. it open and close the sql the connection each time.. which leads to populate your desire result much slower..

```
        var interestIds = db.Interests.Where(i => i.Name.Contains("interest_name"))
                        .Select(i => i.InterestId)
                        .ToList().ConvertAll(i => i.ToString());
        //var profiles = new List<UserProfile>();

        var allProfiles = (from UserProfile up in db.UserProfiles
                           from i in interestIds
                           where up.Interests.Contains(i)
                           select up).ToList();
        return allProfiles;

        //string sId = null;
        //foreach (var id in interestIds)
        //{
        //    sId = id.ToString();
        //    profiles.AddRange(db.UserProfiles
        //        .Where(p => p.Interests.Contains(sId))
        //        .ToList());
        //}
        //return profiles;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works but partially. When I have Interest Id as 1 & a User profile with Interests "5,11" or "11,12", its also selecting these profiles which is wrong by sense.

Comment: Yes I have but I had mostly worked on EF with Linq. I am not familiar with stored procedures. If you have a solution, I'll try it.